# Передать HTML страницу как параметр в метод контроллера

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Каким способом можно передать весь код HTML страницы в контроллер ASP.NET?

View подвергается пользовательскому изменению и после нажатия кнопки "Сохранить", необходимо передать страницу (лучше, конечно, определенный блок) в контроллер.

Насколько я понял нужно использовать AJAX? А что если асинхронность не требуется, т.е. в контроллере будет произведен редирект?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно передать как JSON-строку в связке с `AJAX`:

```
var htmlTableValue = "<HTML>
<table>
<tr><TD> 12 <TD></tr>
</table>
</HTML>";

var request = $.ajax({
                url: '',//action method url which defined in controller
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(htmlTableValue),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });



[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult nameOfTheAction(string htmlTableValue)
   {
   }
```